# How to update initial data in realm after update of apk?

Tags: android, realm

In the app there is a realm database that has both initial data and data added by the user. The data added by the user should stay on the device even after the updates. The initial data is added through the class

```
public class RealmInitialData implements Realm.Transaction {

    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm){
     //initial data
        Items item = new Items();
        item.setName("Fragrance");
        item.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        realm.insertOrUpdate(item);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return RealmInitialData.class.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof RealmInitialData;
    }
}
```

The configuration (situated in a class which extends Application class) looks like this:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("tasky.realm")
                .schemaVersion(2)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .initialData(new RealmInitialData())
                .build();
```

If I change/add something in the RealmInitialData for update, the data on the user application doesn't change. How can I both change the initial data (add or rewrite sth) and make no changes to the user's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement RealmMigration and pass it to `RealmConfiguration.Builder().migration()`. 
Something like this:

```
public class RealmMigrationAgent implements RealmMigration
{
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            schema.get("InventDisableObject").addField("Reason", int.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }

        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            if (!schema.get("ActionObject").hasField("Annual"))
                schema.get("ActionObject").addField("Annual", boolean.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
        if (oldVersion == 2) {
            if (!schema.get("ActionObject").hasField("Hash"))
                schema.get("ActionObject").addField("Hash", String.class);
            if (!schema.get("ActionObject").hasField("Manual"))
                schema.get("ActionObject").addField("Manual", boolean.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
        if (oldVersion == 3) {
            if (!schema.get("OutletObject").hasField("Code"))
                schema.get("OutletObject").addField("Code", String.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

Incrementally adding scheme updates for every new scheme version.
I can see you have some class `Migration` for migration reason - can you provide the code of it?

Comment: Basically, I don't have any field added/deleted from my models class. I need just to change database initial data after an update. So the migration won't solve the problem. 
The problem is in this string .initialData(new RealmInitialData()) - it goes there only when the application is installed. I need it to go there after update too.

Comment: help to initialData()  says it only works in 2 cases: new database created and if deleteRealmIfMigrationisNeeded (or similar - can't remember exactly)set to true (which also destroys any data in database). So if you need data to be added and keep previous data - you can I assume - up scheme version and use migration agent to strictly add data, or use some value in database for last version, check it against new version and if update happened - add it, or something like that.

Comment: Ok. What should I write then in migration to  "strictly add data"? Will it go again into the RealmInitialData class or I need to create another class to add these new components. And how should I include this in migration?

Comment: probably the same code that you use to add objects in RealmInitalData. Or create the object of it, if data is added in `onCreate()` or constructor. 
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
// create your initial data object here that suitable for this version
        } ...
don't forget keep all history of versions in so user can update from any version to last. the code will be executed incrementally for ever new version.

Comment: never used Migration class to add any data though - might have some issues.. better if you tried 2nd variant first.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i find the way.For example,if your new version is 7,try to use `SharedRealm.getInstance(config).getSchemaVersion()` to get the old version 6 before `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)`,then you can update old realm data after `setDefaultConfiguration` which old version < 7.May this can help you:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(7)
            .migration(new RealmMigration() {
                @Override
                public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
                    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
                    if(oldVersion == 6) {
                        schema.get("ImageRealm")
                                .addField("isSelected", Boolean.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                                .addField("isLow", Boolean.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
                        oldVersion++;
                    }
                }
            }).build();

    SharedRealm sharedRealm = SharedRealm.getInstance(config);
    long oldVersion = sharedRealm.getSchemaVersion();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    long newVersion = Realm.getDefaultInstance().getVersion();

    // 如果有历史记录，更新状态
    if (oldVersion < 7) {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<DocRealmBean> allData = realm.where(DocRealmBean.class).findAll();
                for (DocRealmBean bean : allData) {
                    bean.state = "0";
                }
            }
        });
    }
```